# Equivalence of existence of solution in rationals and solution in integers of polynomial equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

**Example** -- We know that $\forall$ n $\in\mathbb{N}$, if solution of equations x$^{2}$ = n or x$^{2}$ + y$^{2}$ = n exist in rationals, then solution also exists in integers.

**Question** --  I was wondering what other equations have similar properties that existence of solutions in rationals implies existence of solution in integers.

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=n$ – because there are *always* solutions in integers.

Comment: Any monic polynomial equation in one variable with integer coefficients has this property.

Comment: @GerryMyerson that second example from you is funny. Lets say that is trivial case and we don't care. Since I forgot to write the first one, lets accept that one.

Comment: Fine, it's your question – but your first example is a special case of my second example.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  these are what Pete called ADC forms; among the positive ternary (quadratic) forms there are 103 of them. http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Clark_Jagy_11_13_2013.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy I'd say for a positive binary quadratic form $q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ with rational coefficients then $q(\Bbb{Q},\Bbb{Q})=N(K)$ represents the norms from a quadratic imaginary number fields $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$ thus $q(\Bbb{Q},\Bbb{Q})\cap \Bbb{Z} = N(O_K)$ while $q(\Bbb{Z},\Bbb{Z})=N(L)= N(c)N(O)$ for some order $O$ and some lattice $L=cO$